# error on query string parameters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I need to start processing a URL that will contain some emailand a GUID. Some thing like following where first param is email address and second param is a Guid.

http://www.myWebSiteurladdress.com/Account/MyActionMethod?MyEmail=me@here.com?MyId=222DF915-264E-4034-BF26-22EB1165667C

For this I have modified my routing as below

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
       "RouteABC", // Route name
       "{controller}/{action}/{mail}/{id}", // URL with parameters
       new { controller = "Account", action = "MyActionMethod", mail = string.Empty, id = Guid.Empty } // Parameter defaults
   );

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Then I have my action method like below.

```
 public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult MyActionMethod(string email, Guid id)
        {

            ............
        }
```

Problem is when I go on the above url, http://www.myWebSiteurladdress.com/Account/MyActionMethod?MyEmail=me@here.com?MyId=222DF915-264E-4034-BF26-22EB1165667C I get following error. Any ideas what I may be doing wrong here?

> The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'MyId'
>   of non-nullable type 'System.Guid' for method
>   'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult MyActionMethod(System.String,
>   System.Guid)' in 'SmartChartsMVC.Controllers.AccountController'. An
>   optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be
>   declared as an optional parameter. Parameter name: parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a single question mark in a properly formatted url. It is what separates the path portion from the query string. So the url you are trying to navigate to is not valid.

A far more realistic url could be the following:

```
http://www.myWebSiteurladdress.com/Account/MyActionMethod/me@here.com/222DF915-264E-4034-BF26-22EB1165667C
```

Also make sure that your route name token matches your action parameter. In your Global.asax route definition you used `{mail}` whereas in your action argument you use `email` as name of the parameter. Make sure you are consistent in your naming convention.

And if you simply wanted to have an url like this:

```
http://www.myWebSiteurladdress.com/Account/MyActionMethod?MyEmail=me@here.com&MyId=222DF915-264E-4034-BF26-22EB1165667C
```

then you don't need to add any custom routes as the default route will be sufficient to call the following action:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult MyActionMethod(string myEmail, Guid myId)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```